# QGIS renders enclosed polygon wrong compared to ArcGIS

Tags: qgis, arcgis-desktop, geometry

I have a street pavement polygon shapefile that is enclosed and hollow on the inside. In QGIS the entire polygon becomes a single blob. The file was downloaded from a county FTP site and works fine in ArcGIS but never appears correctly in QGIS. I don't know how to correct the geometry.

The first image is how it correctly appears in ArcGIS and the second is how it renders in QGIS.

[image: ArcGIS]
[image: QGIS]

Comment: How did you bring the shape in?  As a shapefile?

Comment: @Shub Correct, through _Add Vector Layer_ and browsing to the .shp file

Comment: Did you adjust the file inside ArcGIS?  Or is that how it was brought in.  Also is it not being brought in as a line?  It's automatically becoming a polygon?

Comment: Maybe try the polygons to lines tool under Vector > Geometry Tools.

Comment: @Shub I believe the only modification I did was a selection, then exporting it its own shapefile. The file is a polygon in both ArcGIS and QGIS, it is a polygon of street pavement (actual road surface).

Comment: Can you validate the polygon geometry in arcgis to check for errors? Do the same in QGIS? Any gaps or self intersections might cause an error.

Comment: @mixedbredie I used _Check Geometry_ and _Repair Geometry_ and they succeeded in identifying and fixing an incorrect ring order. If you would like to post this as an answer please do so as your idea fixed my problem. Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Can you validate the polygon geometry in arcgis to check for errors? Check and repair geometry tools will do the job. Do the same in QGIS. Any gaps or self intersections might cause an error. The fact that QGIS fills the hole points to an error somewhere. And the more relaxed approach arcgis takes to geometry validity...